# Rails: Validate presence of associations in a many-to-many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to validate presence of clients in User class, but it seems not working. It never pass. I want to create user which has many clients:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :client_users, dependent: :destroy
 has_many :clients, through: :client_users
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_users


 validates_presence_of :name
 validates_presence_of :clients


 end
```

.....

```
class ClientUser < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :client
belongs_to :user

validates_presence_of :client
validates_presence_of :user

accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :client

self.table_name = "clients_users"

end
```

.....

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :person_contacts

has_many :users, through: :client_users
has_many :client_users, dependent: :destroy

has_many :cases, through: :client_cases
has_many :client_cases, dependent: :destroy

accepts_nested_attributes_for :client_users, :person_contacts,  allow_destroy: true

validates_presence_of :name

end
```

....

part of view:

```
= fields_for :clients do |c|
        = c.select :id, Client.all.collect { |c| [c.name, c.id] }, {},  class: "select2-multiple user-clients form-control", multiple: "multiple"
```

and paramaters processing by users controller:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",   "authenticity_token"=>"d33YuCerXTEATlX4toVA==", "user"=>{"name"=>"", "surname"=>"", "email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "address_city"=>"", "address_street"=>"", "address_house_number"=>"", "address_local_number"=>"", "address_postal_code"=>"", "address_postal_code_place"=>"", "phone"=>"", "role_id"=>"4"}, "clients"=>{"id"=>["", "2"]}, "commit"=>"Utwórz użytkownika"}
```

Everything work well without validation, but i need to ensure that user pass clients in users form

Comment: I cant get clients parameter in User model, every time clients is empty array although parameters in controller looks like above

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom validation

```
validate :has_clients

def has_clients
     errors.add(:base,  "There have to be clients") unless clients.size > 0
end
```

Comment: thanks for reply but it doesnt work, i dont know why but it seems like clients is empty array

Comment: sorry, can writ on the mobile.  I will pst back later